# Using incomparables argument within duplicated() in R

Tags: r

I have the following matrix:

```
structure(c(NA, NA, "2, 3, 5, 7", "1, 3, 5, 7", NA, "1, 3, 7", 
"2, 3, 5, 8", "2, 3, 5, 7", "1, 5, 7, 8", "1, 2, 3, 7, 8", "1, 2, 8", 
"2, 3, 5, 7", NA, "3, 5, 6, 7", "1, 3, 6, 7", "2, 3, 5, 8", "2, 3, 5, 7", 
NA, "1, 3, 7", "1, 4", "3, 4, 5, 7", NA, "3, 5, 7", NA, NA, NA, 
"1, 5, 7", "1, 2, 6, 7", NA, NA, "1, 2, 4, 5, 7", "2, 5, 6, 7", 
"1, 4, 6, 7", "2, 5, 8", "2, 5", "5, 8", "2, 6, 7", NA, NA, "2, 7", 
NA, "6, 7", NA, NA, NA, "1, 2", "1, 2, 4", "2, 4", "1, 2, 3, 4, 5", 
"2, 3, 5", NA, NA, NA, NA, "2, 3, 8", "2, 8", NA, NA, "2, 3, 7", 
NA, "3, 5", NA, "5, 7", NA, NA, "2, 3", "2, 3, 7", NA, NA, NA, 
"3, 7", NA, NA, NA, NA, "3, 4", NA, "3, 4", NA, NA, NA), .Dim = c(9L, 
9L))
```

I want to find which elements are duplicated ignoring the missing elements.
I use the following code:

```
duplicated(cand, MARGIN = 0, incomparables = NA)
```

However, this returns the following error:

```
Error: argument 'incomparables != FALSE' is not used (yet)
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The help page `help(duplicated)` says:

> incomparables
>   a vector of values that cannot be compared. FALSE is
>   a special value, meaning that all values can be compared, and may be
>   the only value accepted for methods other than the default. It will be
>   coerced internally to the same type as x.

So `incomparables = NA` seems to not work.  However, you can get the effect that you are looking for with:

```
duplicated(cand, MARGIN = 0) & !is.na(cand)
```

Comment: The solution works. However, the explanation is not true coz trying `incomparables = "3, 4"` gives the same error

Comment: I don't see why you say that the explanation is incorrect. The Explanation says that the _only_ value that is accepted is `incomparables=FALSE`

Comment: Ohhhh... I got it now, sorry. So, what if I want to use `"3, 4"` as incomparable?

Comment: `duplicated(cand, MARGIN = 0) & (cand != "3, 4")`

Comment: Or I think just `duplicated(c(cand), incomparables=c(NA, "3, 4"))` since this is dealing with a matrix and the vector output will work fine for subsetting later on. E.g.: `cand[duplicated(c(cand), incomparables=c(NA, "3, 4"))]` for instance gives the same result.